# QGIS Graphical Modeler not finding output files

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I am going through the GST 102 Module 5 tutorial which uses the graphical modeler. I keep getting this message when trying to use the output of an Extract by attribute algorithm as a clipper for a point layer.

> Prepare algorithm 0: Extract by attribute
>   Running Extract by attribute [1/10]
>   Parameters: LAYERNAME =C:\Projects\qgis\data2\Counties.shp, ATTRIBUTE =COUNTY, COMPARISON =0, COMPARISONVALUE =Nueces
>   Converting outputs
>   Outputs: RESULT =C:/Projects/qgis/data2/Output/NuecesCounty.shp
>   OK. Execution took 0.946 ms (1 outputs).
>   Prepare algorithm 1: Clip
>   Running Clip [2/10]
>   Parameters: INPUT =C:\Projects\qgis\data2\Airports.shp, OVERLAY =C:/Projects/qgis/data2/Output/NuecesCounty.shp
>   Failed
>   Error executing algorithm 1 [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor See log for more details

I have checked and the C:/Projects/qgis/data2/Output/NuecesCounty.shp layer is created during the first process as it should. I am using Windows 7.

Comment: I'm assuming you're wanting to clip a point layer with a polygon layer? In which case, try setting the point layer as the **input** and the polygon layer as the **clip**.

Comment: Yes, the airports layer is the point layer that I am using for input. The clip layer is the output from the Extract by Attribute process which creates a temporary file. I think that is where the problem is. Perhaps the write process does not complete before the next read process begins? The tutorial that I'm using is from the foss4geo site and is at: http://foss4geo.files.wordpress.com/2014/08/gst_102_lab_5_vector_data_analysis_creating_a_site_selection_model.pdf

Comment: Which QGIS version are you using? I use 2.2 and I did a test creating only temporary files and it seems to work fine. Have you tried doing it manually (ie. doing each function seperately via the interface)?

Comment: I am using 2.4 because when I use 2.2 I get the message that the tool "has no object OUTPUT", which I guess refers to the output file. I will try loading each function separately as you suggest.